# How to assign values in array based on array keys

Tags: php

How to modify an array based on the value as key?

```
array(
    array(
        "name" => "BIBAR",
        "cutoff" => 20220725,
        "totals" => 5614
    ),
    array(
        "name" => "BIBAR",
        "cutoff" => 20220810,
        "totals" => 5614
    ),
    array(
        "name" => "BIBAR",
        "cutoff" => 20220825,
        "totals" => 5614
    )
);
```

I tried the following but it's not working:

```
foreach($cutoffs as $catoff) {
    $ii = 0;
    $sums[$ii][$catoff] = array_filter($array, function($val){
        return $val['cutoff'] === $catoff ? $val['totals'] : $val;
    });
    $ii++;
}
```

My desired array:

```
array(
    '20221025' => array(
        12345,
        12343,
        24442
    ),
    '20221110' => array(
        3443,
        744334
    )
)
```

I'm stuck here for hours ... Please help

Comment: Please check and [edit] your question, the formatting looks broken. Also consider to write what the not-expected outcome is, just a "not working" is incomplete. See as well [help].

Comment: Please use `var_export()` instead of `print_r()` for dumping.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

IF the "name" is irrelevant, I think also the previous answer should be fine.
If this code does "not work", then your explanation might be wrong, so you need to either explain better, or give us more examples - please mind that **in your example the input and output are very different** - the input you gave does not match your ouput.

My code is:

```php
$a = array(
    array(
        "name" => "BIBAR",
        "cutoff" => 20220725,
        "totals" => 5614
    ),
    array(
        "name" => "BIBAR",
        "cutoff" => 20220810,
        "totals" => 5614
    ),
    array(
        "name" => "BIBAR",
        "cutoff" => 20220725,
        "totals" => 1234
    )
);

print_r($a);


echo "\n================================\n\n";

$newArr = [];

foreach ($a as $k => $vArr) {
    // maybe some validation would be useful here, check if they keys exist
    $newArr[$vArr['cutoff']][] = $vArr['totals'];
}

print_r($newArr);
```

[image]

Answer (score 0):

```
function changeArr($data){
    $new = [];
    foreach ($data as $v){
        $new[$v['cutoff']][] = $v['totals'];
    }
    return $new;
}
```

Comment: Please don't just dump code as an answer, always add some explanation of what may have been the problem and how your code solves OP's problem so others can learn. Thanks